# How do I reassign a user to another profile?

Tags: permissions, profile

I've recently taken over control of Salesforce without any prior experience with it.

I've learned some Apex and am trying to deploy it from sandbox to production but it appears my sandbox User has the profile set to "Systems Administrator", which doesn't have the needed permissions to make Changesets.

I've created a new Profile with the extra permissions and now I'm stuck changing my User to use this Profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an extra Profile to add some permissions to individual user(s). For that just use a Salesforce feature called `Permition set` (you can learn [more about it here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=perm_sets_overview.htm&language=en_US)).

> A permission set is a collection of settings and permissions that give
>   users access to various tools and functions.

So you can extend users permitions without changing his profile or creating a new one.

If you still need to reassign users profile, go to Setup > Manage Users > Users and click on the user you need. Then click on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button. Now you can edit the `Profile` list. It is based on the `User License` entry.

Comment: All I have when i'm editing that is the following: http://imgur.com/MKSr5wG   I can follow the System Administrator link to edit settings in the current Profile but as it's a Salesforce Profile and so I'm not allowed to edit it.

Comment: @Josh_at_Savings_Champion Which profile you have yourself?

Comment: System Administrator, I'm editing my account to have System Administrator Privileges + Developer Privileges by creating a DevOps Profile and moving myself to it.